# Issues with forms using Ruby Mechanize

Tags: ruby, forms, http, mechanize

I am trying to automate getting a certain report from a web service my company uses.  I've been using the Mechanize gem, and I was able to get other reports from the same service using it.

When I submit the form that generates the report, all I get back in response is headers of the CSV.  It should be returning more than that, obviously.

I've used the Chrome Dev Tools to see what the expected values for each field are, and I've mimicked them.  No matter what I try, though, I just can't get the service to return the expected values.

What should I try?  What might I be doing wrong?

Edit: Code in question

```
@loginpage = 'service_uri'

agent = Mechanize.new

login_page = agent.get @loginpage
login_form = login_page.form
email_field = login_form.field_with(name: "Email")
password_field = login_form.field_with(name: "Password")

email_field.value = 'service_login'
password_field.value = 'service_password'

page = login_form.submit

transaction_page = page.link_with(text: 'Transaction History').click


transaction_form = transaction_page.form_with(action: "/reports/transactionhistory/transactionreportexport")

transaction_form['IncludeSupplier'] = "false"
transaction_form['IncludeBrand'] = "false"
transaction_form['IncludeClassification'] = "false"
transaction_form['IncludeAttributes'] = "false"
transaction_form['IncludeScannedCode'] = "false"

transaction_form['Reason'] = ""
transaction_form['Type'] = "AddItem"
transaction_form['WarehouseId'] = "0"
transaction_form['UserLocaleInfo.Locale'] = "en-US"
transaction_form['UserLocaleInfo.TimeZoneOffset'] = "-360"

dateToday = Date.today-2
dateTomorrow = Date.today-1

transaction_form['StartDate'] = "\"#{dateToday.to_s}-T06:00:00.000Z\""
transaction_form['EndDate'] = "\"#{dateTomorrow.to_s}-T05:59:59.999Z\""

transaction_form.submit
```

Comment: can you show the controller action, and the code to make the request?

Comment: This is a straight Ruby script.  This isn't a Rails app or anything, I'm just trying to use Ruby + Mechanize to get the report from a web service.

Comment: Added to the main post

Comment: You should try proxying both the browser request and the mechanize request through Fiddler and compare them. Somewhere there is a difference.

Comment: What's Fiddler, and how do I do that?

Comment: I started using Fiddler, and while most requests are going through it, it seems like the ones of any interest... aren't.